# Dynamic arguments for Python functions

Tags: python, arguments

I have a list of lists, and I would like to enter them into a function in such a way that each element of the main list is a different argument to the function.

```
squares = [[1,5,9,13], [2,6,10,14], [3,7,11,15], [4,8,12,16]]
print zip(squares[0], squares[1], squares[2], squares[3])
# displays [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
```

Is there a way to do something like `print zip(arguments(squares))` so that the arguments can be entered dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `*` operator is for:

```
print zip(*squares)
```